# Record syntax `parse error on input ‘=’`

Tags: haskell

I have a do block in my Yesod tests and I want to be test the response with an expected response.

I attempted to create an expected response in this do block

```
let expectedUser = User [authorized = true, ident = "AdminUser", displayName = Nothing, id = 1, avatar = Nothing]
```

On this line I get the error

```
parse error on input ‘=’
Perhaps you need a 'let' in a 'do' block?
```

on the = after `authorized`. How would I rewrite this line so that it would work inside a do block?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The advice you're getting in the compile error is mostly irrelevant, because the parser really has no idea what you're trying to do here. Record syntax uses curly braces `{` and `}`, not `[` and `]`. So it should look like:

```
let expectedUser = User {authorized = true, ident = "AdminUser", displayName = Nothing, id = 1, avatar = Nothing}
```

and I would suggest some line breaks :)

```
let expectedUser = User { authorized = true
                        , ident = "AdminUser"
                        , displayName = Nothing
                        , id = 1
                        , avatar = Nothing
                        }
```